# How to get native code of flink from apache beam build file?

Tags: apache-flink, apache-beam

I defined a pipline of stream processing with Apache Beam and I build it for Fling runner.

I got a jar file, but when I extracted the java files, the java code is not a native Flink code.

Though I found some generated code in my classe:

```
 // $FF: synthetic method
 private static Object $deserializeLambda$(SerializedLambda lambda) {
  String var1 = lambda.getImplMethodName();
  byte var2 = -1;
  switch(var1.hashCode()) {
  case -30470307:
     if (var1.equals("lambda$main$fd9fc9ef$1")) {
        var2 = 1;
     }
     break;
  case -30470306:
     if (var1.equals("lambda$main$fd9fc9ef$2")) {
        var2 = 0;
     }
  }
```

Is there any generated file with Flink code?

Regards,
Ali

Comment: It translates to Flink model on runtime. You won't get Flink code. If you check the logs you should see the transformation steps. Check the Flink runner source code to see how that works.

Comment: As Piotr mentioned, here is the Flink runner code: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a63d0b338c4b62896b1677d2ac81a09992d6cde3/runners/flink/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/flink/TestFlinkRunner.java , then the key part is the translation logic, for example translations for batch transforms: https://github.com/apache/beam/blob/a63d0b338c4b62896b1677d2ac81a09992d6cde3/runners/flink/src/main/java/org/apache/beam/runners/flink/FlinkBatchTransformTranslators.java

Comment: Thanks for your answers.